# Attaching to click event (with jQuery) on submit button kills submission function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

The full story is I want to disable the submit button on a form's submission to prevent multiple submissions. One of the problems is the form is an ASP.Net MVC Ajax form - <% using (Ajax.BeginForm ... %> - so its javascript onSubmit event is already set and I therefore cannot do this during that event. Unless there's a way to *add* to the submit event with jQuery? My testing shows that $("#form").submit(...) *replaces* the submit event and thusly kills MVC's ajaxy stuff.

So what I've done is attached the button-disabling code to the submit button's click event. That works fine ... only it kills the button's submission abilities (nothing happens other than the button gets disabled). I took it a step further and used jQuery to submit the form from the click event. This borks everything, the ajax response comes back as a downloaded file, I assume because MVC's ajax stuff got clobbered again.  This is where I'm at:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function ()
{
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.parent().submit();
    $button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Any one know a work-around?

Edit:
So, turns out this actually may be a bug in MVC. Originally I had:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAsync", "Account", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnComplete = "create_Complete",
        OnBegin = "create_Begin"
    },
    new { id = "ajaxForm" }))
{ %>
<!-- form stuff -->
<% } %>

$("#ajaxForm").submit(function() {
    $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Notice I was setting the form's ID and grabbing a jQuery handle to it via that ID. Looks like the simple fact that I'm setting the ID of the form is causing all the issues.  In fact, I can break the form submission w/o any jQuery intervention what-so-ever if I set the form ID. So this works totally as advertised:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAsync", "Account", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnComplete = "create_Complete",
        OnBegin = "create_Begin"
    }))
{ %>
<!-- form stuff -->
<% } %>

$("form").submit(function() {
    $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: `.submit()` *adds* an event handler, that's where you should do this (it doesn't replace it), can you elaborate more on that attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug. See the edited question for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically something like

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() { return false; });
    $(":submit", this).addClass("PseudoDisabled");
});
```

attached on document.ready works well in our project. As you cannot actually disable the submit button or the postback will be ignored. We basically created a disabled style that is applied onSubmit that gives the appearance of disabled and prevents multiple submits by attached a new submit event handler.

Comment: Very nice, although I suggest an `unbind` to remove useless event handlers.

Comment: @digitalFresh - Probably not a bad idea to be safe.

Comment: Ah, I see, very clever. Yeah, I was wondering if it was the simple fact that setting the "disable" property is what was *actually* preventing the form submission. I'll give it a try ...

Comment: This really looks like a bug in MVC / ASP.Net Ajax. See my edits. Perhaps you don't need your work-around after all?

Comment: @xanadont - Not MVC in my case... but definitely worth knowing.